# PI controller - output calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, drag, aerodynamics, aircraft, laplace-transform

The propeller of an airship is connected to a DC motor. The motor is being controlled using a PI controller. The PI controller has a proportional gain of Kp = 2, and an integral gain of Ki = 0.5, and the controller's input is the speed error, which is the difference between the desired and measured speeds. It follows the equation:

Output = Kp×Error + Ki×∫Error dt

If the desired speed is 500 rpm and the measured speed is 480 rpm, what will be the controller's output after 10 seconds?

My approach:
Considering 10 seconds to be an instance, I assumed the error signal to be independent of time.
Thus,
output= 2(20) + (0.5)(20)(10)= 140

This feels wrong on so many levels but I am not able to figure out how else to go about this.
Anyone ?

Comment: Please try to turn this into a question about the concepts underlying your equations. We need something more specific than "this feels wrong".

Comment: i just want to know how the question is to be solved.